# "War" card game generator questions, using classes and objects (java 7)

Tags: java

My question today is, how can I assign values for my state variables/methods, in order to compare values to determine the winner? 
Also, how do I direct the values to "Jack" and "Jill" (player p1 and p2)?

Should I use if-else statements?

And last question: why does my console print "null" for my getScore, getcardSuit, getcardValue, etc??
(I will give you my console printout after all of this)

Here is my code for my "player class", and my "tester" project is below this code (to test my player class):

```
public class player {


// The two players are going to enter:

String p1[] = {"Jack", "h", "k"};
String p2[] = {"Jill", "d", "9"};

//Setting up values

String Jack = "Jack";
String Jill = "Jill";
String h = " Hearts ";
String d = " Diamonds ";
String k = " King ";
int val = 9;

// Score

public int score = 0; // State variable score, set equal to 0


// Player name - Jack, Jill

public player(String Jack, String h, String k) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


public String playerName(String player)
{
    player = "Jack";
    player = "Jill";
    return player;
}


// Card suit

public String cardSuit(String getcardSuit)
{

    return cardSuit;

}

// Card Value for player 1


public String getCardValue() 
{

    return cardValue;
}

public String getScore(String score)
{
    return score;
}


public String player;
public String playerName;
public String cardSuit;
public String cardValue;
public double getScore;


public String getCardSuit() 
{
    return cardSuit;
}


public int getScore() {

    return 0;
}
}
```

Here is my "Tester", to test my "player class":

```
public class Tester {



public static void main(String[] args) {


    // Create an object for player 1 
    player p1 = new player("Jack", "h", "k");

    // Create an object for player 2
    player p2 = new player("Jill", "d", "9");

    // Use p1 object and methods getCardSuit and getCardValue to report p1's card

    System.out.println(p1.playerName+"'s card is a "+p1.getCardValue()+" of "+p1.getCardSuit()+"."); 

        // Should print:

            // Jack's card is a King of Hearts.

    // Use p2 object and methods getCardSuit and getCardValue to report p2's card

    System.out.println(p2.playerName+"'s card is a "+p2.getCardValue()+" of "+p2.getCardSuit()+"."); 

        // Should print:    

            // Jill's card is a 9 of Diamonds.


    // Compare player's scores to determine winner

    if(p1.getScore()>p2.getScore())
        System.out.println(p1.playerName+" is the winner!");
    else if (p1.getScore()<p2.getScore());
        System.out.println(p2.playerName+" is the winner!");

        // Should print:
            // "Jack is the winner!"



        }
}
```

CONSOLE:

null's card is a null of null.
null's card is a null of null.
null is the winner!

- how can I fix this "null" stuff and actually have their values printed??
  Thanks so much, in advance! :)

Comment: It's difficult to know where to start.

Comment: This might give clues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278445/ruby-war-card-game-dealing-cards-to-players

Comment: *why does my console print "null"* ? seriously... try debugger.

Comment: @Zhedar Well, that wasn't very helpful

Answer (score 2):

I'll start by answering the question you asked:

The values are null because they were never initialized. Your constructor for the `player` class:

```
public player(String Jack, String h, String k) {
    // does absolutely nothing with the values.
}
```

does nothing. This means you created a new player `player1` and a new player `player2` but didn't actually use the values to do anything at all.

```
player p1 = new player("Jack", "h", "k");
```

calls the constructor, sends in values and the values are ignored. An instance of player1 is created and absolutely nothing is done with the information. You, therefore, cannot compare the values to each other since they have not been initialized.

**Other considerations**

When you make a class, in object oriented programming you should think in an OO sort of way.

The player class can/should have a `String name;` variable and you can then create a Player object and pass the name, exactly like you did. The difference is in your constructor:

```
//Setting up values

String name;
String suit;
String value;

public player(String name, String suit, String value) {
    this.name = name;
    this.suit = suit;
    this.value = value;
}
```

This technique creates a player1 object with a name, a suit and a value. Now the values within this object can be compared to equal values in another player object if you so choose.

Comment: @Sophie Glad I could help. Don't forget to accept the answer you feel best solves your problem, answers are just as important as questions here on SO. And welcome to the community.

Answer (score 0):

So I tried to clean up your Player class a bit:

```
public class Player 
{
    // The two players are going to enter:

    String p1[] = {"Jack", "h", "k"};
    String p2[] = {"Jill", "d", "9"};

    //Setting up values

    String jack = "Jack";
    String jill = "Jill";
    String h = " Hearts ";
    String d = " Diamonds ";
    String k = " King ";
    int val = 9;
    // Score

    public int score = 0; // State variable score, set equal to 0

    // Player name - Jack, Jill

    public Player(String jack, String h, String k) 
    {
        this.jack = jack;
        this.h = h;
        this.k = k;
    }


    public String playerName(String player)
    {
        // not sure what this is doing?
        // this first line does nothing at all
        // because player gets reassigned to "Jill"
        player = "Jack";
        player = "Jill";
        return player;
    }


    // Card suit

    public String cardSuit(String getcardSuit)
    {
        return cardSuit;
    }

    // Card Value for player 1

    public String getCardValue() 
    {
        return cardValue;
    }

    public String getScore(String score)
    {
        return score;
    }

    public String player;
    public String playerName;
    public String cardSuit;
    public String cardValue;
    public double getScore;

    public String getCardSuit() 
    {
        return cardSuit;
    }

    public int getScore() 
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

There are a couple of conventions you should start using. Class names should start with an uppercase letter. Variables and stuff like that should all have lower case letters (unless it is a static).

Comment: Thank you for taking time to help me. I really appreciate it, and it was very helpful.
:)